How to make remove unused imports warnings when are used as a parameter (VSC)
Hi I got unused imports warnings in VSC. My file:
import * as en from '../../src/assets/i18n/en.json'
import * as fi from '../../src/assets/i18n/fi.json'
import * as sv from '../../src/assets/i18n/sv.json'

async checkFields(language) {
    await expect(this.heading).toContainText(
      language.EinvoicesProductRegister_Heading_Title,
    )

on en.json  file I got this:
"EinvoicesProductRegister_Heading_Title": "Products and services",

and I also use that checkFields method in other file:
 test('Check Product register page fields', async ({ page }) => {
    const productRegister = new ProductRegister(page)
    productRegister.checkFields('en')
  })

What should I do if I want these unused imports are not be treated as a unused in VSC when these imports are used as a parameter?

Based on the code you've shown, the variables you're declaring (specifically, en, fi, sv) aren't used anywhere in the code. So I'm not sure what the source of confusion is--the error is correct and you can either use the variables or remove the imports. What do you mean by "used as a parameter"? I don't see these vars used as parameters, either, although that'd be another declaration. Please share a [mcve] showing you actually using the variables, yet the error still shows up.

@ggorlen See productRegister.checkFields('en') in the question. en is used as an argument.  Probably nothing can be done to tell tsc that is the same as the import though.

@Mark That's a string, not a variable. A string that happens to have the same characters as a variable does not constitute using that variable. It's totally unrelated.

@ggorlen Clearly it is a string, but look at how he is using it.  He wants "en" to be recognized as the import variable.  That is the issue here..  A mapping to the en variable might solve it for him.

@Mark Sorry, I'm not sure what you're suggesting here. How could a string be "recognized as the import variable"? A string is a string, a variable is a variable. I'm not sure what a "mapping to the en variable" means. If you understand this, feel free to add an answer though.

OK, I see OP's intent based on the answer. Still seems easier to just pass the variable in instead of mapping magic strings to variables, and in any case, OP's question isn't the correct one (they're asking why they get an unused variable linter error, when they should be asking why their code isn't working at all, because the json files are currently completely ignored/unused).

As already mentioned in comments the imports are not used in your code, which is the crux of your issue. But the rest of the comments are less helpful.
The issue is very basic, which indicates you would be well served by studying some programming examples. In any case, step-by-step:

you pass a value en into the function to indicate you want to use this particular language.

you need to relate or "map" that value to one of the imports you have at the top of the file

you can use a sequence of if() statements or you can use a switch() statement, or you can use a mapping object. The mapping object is my preference so I will show it here.


import * as en from '../../src/assets/i18n/en.json'
import * as fi from '../../src/assets/i18n/fi.json'
import * as sv from '../../src/assets/i18n/sv.json'

const languageMap = {
  'en': en,
  'fi': fi,
  'sv': sv
}

async checkFields(languageValue) {     // the parameter indicates the language
                                       // i.e when I see string "en"
                                       // I know I need to pick the en import

  const language = languageMap[languageValue]  // use the map to pick 
                                               // the right json import

  await expect(this.heading).toContainText(
    language.EinvoicesProductRegister_Heading_Title,
  )

You should research and try out the other methods I mention as your skills need improving - the resolution of this question should be very obvious to anyone wishing to use Playwright.

Odd that you state the rest of the comments are "less helpful" but then you suggest my mapping solution.

It seems pretty obvious what comments are being referred to.

Just a note that Typescript will not be happy with
const languageMap = {
  'en': en,
  'fi': fi,
  'sv': sv
}

when used in const language = languageMap[languageValue];
It will complain about using the string key languageValue as an index into the languageMap object.  One way to fix that is to use this:
const languageMap: Record<string, any>  = {
  'en': en,
  'fi': fi,
  'sv': sv
};

which is similar to
const languageMap: { [key: string]: any } = {
  'en': en
  // etc.
};

For more on this type of Typescript problem, see expression of type 'string' can't be used as an index.
